# How to rank using Learning to Rank Algorithms

Tags: xgboost

I am new to Learning to Rank and trying it out using XGBRanker. I have viewed a lot of articles which mention that if ranks are given from 1-5, 5 is the most relevant and 1 is the least. The scores generated by XGBRanker in pairwise approach are sorted in the descending order signifying the relevance.

I want to take a different approach. I want my rank 1 to be the most relevant. In this case how should I go about solving this problem ?

Comment: Are you using the pairwise approach as explained in this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_to_rank#Pairwise_approach ? If so inverting `xu` and `xv` like  `CDF(f(xv) - f(xu))` should work.

Comment: The major doubt i have is during pairwise, the model gives out a list of float numbers, higher the better. But in my case if 1 is the best and 5 is the worst.. should I consider the lower float values as the most relevant or it should be the same for both cases?

Comment: If you know for sure your minimum and maximum values are 1 and 5, you can also obtain your score with this simple formula `score = max - CDF(f(xu) - f(xv))` (here `max = 5`). The advantage with this formula is you don't have to invert the positions of `xu` and `xv`.